# how to make antd-form-builder select field searchable (react)?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-forms

I am trying to create a form using antd-form-builder how can I make its select field searchable?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'antd'
import FormBuilder from 'antd-form-builder'

export default () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm()

  const meta = {
    columns: 2
    fields: [
      { key: 'select', label: 'Select', widget: 'select', options: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'] },
    ]

return (
    <Form form={form}>
      <FormBuilder meta={meta} form={form} />
      <Form.Item className="form-footer">
        <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each field in `antd-form-builder` is a widget, you can pass all the select props that for that particular by passing `widgetProps` as prop.

For example, to make select widget/field as searchable, you can pass `showSearch: true`.

```
const meta = {
    columns: 2,
    fields: [
      {
        key: "select",
        label: "Select",
        widget: "select",
        options: ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"],
        widgetProps: { showSearch: true },
      },
    ],
  };
```

You can follow the antd documentation to check what type of props you can pass to select field.

[Antd Select Props API](https://ant.design/components/select/#Select-props)